# events handle in classic ASP

Tags: events, asp-classic

I'm using ChartFX to create charts in classic ASP pages.

I need to catch the event "GetPointLabel" on my chart object (server side), but I can't manage to do it... Here's my code (which doesn't work: the function is never fired):

> Private Sub Chart1_GetPointLabel(ByVal sender, ByVal args) 
>         'some handling code
>       End Sub

Is this the right way to handle events in classic ASP ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: how are you creating your chart object?

Comment: Set Chart1 = Server.CreateObject("ChartFX.ASP.Server")